# Adding integer to database Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone

My objective here is taking the score from my gamePage.xaml, and inserting it into the database on MainPage.xaml and displaying it.

I followed a tutorial on creating a .sdf file for the database and having that come up. I thought that I could just declare a `newToDo` and set it to the score and insert it into the database.

Either I am doing something wrong or it is not working.

Here is some of my code.

```
   private void newToDoAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToDoItem newToDo = new ToDoItem { ItemName = newToDoTextBox.Text };
        string Score = gamePage.buttonCount.ToString();
       //this is the string variable that I want to be inserted into database

        ToDoItems.Add(newToDo);
        //I want the newToDo to be my string score

        toDoDB.ToDoItems.InsertOnSubmit(newToDo);
       //insert score into database and save it
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide a little bit of information on how the LINQ works. Whenever you make `SomethingOnSubmit` call, LINQ takes note of that change. Same is true if you are updating an existing record by changing the value like this:

```
itemToUpdate.ItemName = "My Awesome Item";
```

Then finally, when you call `SubmitChanges` on your `DataContext` object, all the changes you have made are translated to SQL queries and those queries are executed. Your changes are actually written after you do `SubmitChanges` call. So, in your code, you'll need to do the following:

```
toDoDB.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call this method

```
toDoDB.SubmitChanges();
```

after **InsertOnSubmit(newToDo);**

Comment: I get that you call the method, but I'm just not understanding how I am supposed to insert the string score into the database? I just need to know how to declare what I'm putting in it. newToDo for example.

Comment: Just found out! Thanks for the help. I had to make a ToDoItem scores = new ToDoItem { ItemName = score };